# crash with admob and startActivity

Tags: java, android, android-intent, admob

I'm using `intent` in my program to share image and text.

Everything worked fine till AdMob banner was added. The program crashes when it goes to `startActivity`. It doesn't happen every time, but about 30% ratio.

Here is code for launching external intent.

```
private void _share(String text) {
    Log.w("A", "share");
    Intent intent=new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    intent.setType("image/*");
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_WHEN_TASK_RESET);

    File file = new File("/sdcard/dodgegame.jpg");
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(file));
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, text);
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "How do you want to share?"));
}
```

AdMob works well itself. Ads are displayed correctly. It seems all the crashes happen when startActivity and new ad comes to AdMob at the same time (not sure), because every time when it crashes, I can see admob log like `Ads  onReceiveAd()`

Here is log when it crashes:

```
09-15 00:23:23.540: I/Choreographer(18986): Skipped 30 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
09-15 00:23:33.451: I/Ads(19125): onReceiveAd()
09-15 00:23:34.232: W/A(19125): share
09-15 00:23:34.272: W/crash_handler(19125): Caught a crash, signum=11
09-15 00:23:34.272: E/webcore(19125): Report WebCore crash to the ErrorReportUtils at:Sun Sep 15 00:23:34 格林尼治标准时间+0800 2013
```

Has anyone experienced?

The intent worked well before AdMob was added, so I think this could be a bug of AdMob. If so, I'll have to find a way to temporarily disable AdMob.

Additional infomation:

1. AdMob JAR: GoogleAdMobAdsSdk-6.4.1.jar
2. Android sdk: mac-x86_64-20130729 / android-18
3. The function `_share` is called from cocos2dx via JNI (does that matter?)

Comment: where you have added the ads in your code ?

Comment: It will be better if you keep your ads code in the separate thread from the main UI thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I worked it out!

Realized it's a thread issue, `startActivity` was called in cocos2dx thread, I moved `startActivity` into the main UI thread by `Handler`. And crash never happened again.

So I created a `Handler` in `onCreate`:

```
private Handler handler;
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    // ... blah blah
    handler = new Handler();
}
```

Then call `startActivity` in a `Runnable`:

```
private void share() {
    handler.post(new Runnable(){
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // ... create intent
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```